# Using jq, select multiple keys and return them in an array

Tags: jq

Given this array:

```
[{"Key":"base_ami","Value":"ami-46d003ac"},
{"Key":"app","Value":"amibuild"},
{"Key":"sbu","Value":"IT"},
{"Key":"base_ami_image_location","Value":"123456789012/amazon-linux"},
{"Key":"app_env","Value":"dev"},
{"Key":"Name","Value":"amazon-linux"},
{"Key":"jenkins_build_id","Value":"24"},
{"Key":"os_type","Value":"linux"},
{"Key":"version","Value":"1.0.24"}]
```

I want this output:

```
[{"Key":"app","Value":"amibuild"},{"Key":"sbu","Value":"IT"},{"Key":"app_env","Value":"dev"}]
```

I've got it down as far as this:

```
.[] | select(.Key == "app"), select(.Key == "app_env"), select(.Key == "sbu")
```

but that results in:

```
{"Key":"app","Value":"amibuild"}
{"Key":"sbu","Value":"IT"}
{"Key":"app_env","Value":"dev"}
```

I need those individual objects returned as elements of an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to wrap the result in `[...]`:

```
[.[] | select(.Key == "app"), select(.Key == "app_env"), select(.Key == "sbu")]
```

You can also shorten this filter slightly:

```
[.[] | select(.Key == "app" or .Key == "app_env" or .Key == "sbu")]
```

Or use the `map` function:

```
map(select(.Key == "app" or .Key == "app_env" or .Key == "sbu"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Small improvement on @chepner's answer that's a bit more concise:

```
map(select(.Key == ("app", "app_env", "sbu")))
```